# HTML Nav above main div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i got a sidenav from W3 schools and it works like i want it to. But i can't get the icon of the menu to go over the other content on my page. It just goes above. I've also done absolute positioning but to no succes. If i do that the navbar displays wrong.

Any suggestions would help.
I've included a code snippet.

So i would like the sidenav icon to be on top of the picture.

```js
function w3_open() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
}
function w3_close() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}

function myAccFunc() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demoAcc");
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        x.previousElementSibling.className =
        x.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-green", "");
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

BODY {
    font-family: FuturaLight;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.margin {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: animateleft 0.4s;
    animation: animateleft 0.4s;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #616161 !important;
}

.sidenav a{
    display: block;
}

.accordion {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.opennav:hover, .closenav:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size:24px!important
}

.opennav, .closenav {
    color: inherit;
    font-size:24px!important;
    z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<BODY>
  <nav class="sidenav" style="display:none" id="mySidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()"
       class="closenav">Sluiten &times;</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <div class="accordion">
        <a onclick="myAccFunc()" href="#">
            Accordion <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <div id="demoAcc" class="w3-accordion-content w3-white w3-card-4">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
</nav>

<span class="opennav" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</span>
  
    <img src="http://static.nationalgeographic.nl/uploads/media/image/photo-ark-alle-dieren-verzameld-foto-van-de-dag.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: just add .opennav{position:absolute;color:#fff} and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS properties  `float: left`  and `position: absolute`  on the `.opennav` element  to achieve the effect of floating in front of the image, as opposed to being above it..

**EDIT**
Then to fix the icon from showing up on the sidenav, simply change the `z-index` of the sidenav to `998`  and the z-index of the icon to `997` so that the icon appears under the side nav

```js
function w3_open() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
}

function w3_close() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}

function myAccFunc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demoAcc");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    x.previousElementSibling.className =
      x.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-green", "");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}
BODY {
  font-family: FuturaLight;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.margin {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed !important;
  z-index: 998;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: animateleft 0.4s;
  animation: animateleft 0.4s;
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #616161 !important;
}
.sidenav a {
  display: block;
}
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.opennav:hover,
.closenav:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 24px!important
}
.opennav {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px!important;
  z-index: 995;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
.closenav {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px!important;
  z-index: 999;

}
```

```html
<BODY>
  <nav class="sidenav" style="display:none" id="mySidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="closenav">Sluiten &times;</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <div class="accordion">
      <a onclick="myAccFunc()" href="#">
            Accordion <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
      <div id="demoAcc" class="w3-accordion-content w3-white w3-card-4">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  </nav>

  <span class="opennav" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</span>

  <img src="http://static.nationalgeographic.nl/uploads/media/image/photo-ark-alle-dieren-verzameld-foto-van-de-dag.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just added `position: absolute;` and it behaves like you want.

**Changed the styling for img tag now looks good.**

```js
function w3_open() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
}
function w3_close() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}

function myAccFunc() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demoAcc");
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        x.previousElementSibling.className =
        x.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-green", "");
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

BODY {
    font-family: FuturaLight;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.margin {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: animateleft 0.4s;
    animation: animateleft 0.4s;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #616161 !important;
}

.sidenav a{
    display: block;
}

.accordion {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.opennav:hover, .closenav:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size:24px!important
}

.opennav, .closenav {
    color: inherit;
    font-size:24px!important;
    z-index:999;
    color: #ffffff;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -99999;
}
```

```html
<BODY>
  <nav class="sidenav" style="display:none" id="mySidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()"
       class="closenav">Sluiten &times;</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <div class="accordion">
        <a onclick="myAccFunc()" href="#">
            Accordion <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <div id="demoAcc" class="w3-accordion-content w3-white w3-card-4">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
</nav>

<span class="opennav" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</span>
  
    <img src="http://static.nationalgeographic.nl/uploads/media/image/photo-ark-alle-dieren-verzameld-foto-van-de-dag.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: Yes indeed at first glance it does. I've tryed that but when you open the menu things don't look right as you can see.

Comment: @JariFlederick What about the new changes?

Comment: @JariFlederick The alternate you can also play with ```z-index```.

Comment: Mike210a his answer seemed to work as intended. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Add position:absolute in the styling of .opennav, .closenav classes.